# How to customize y axis for bar chart in c3 js to display custom percentage ticks

Tags: user-interface, charts, c3.js

I want to have custom percentage ticks on y axis in c3 js bar chart where percentage axis should display 0, 25%, 50%, 75% and 100% only.

What should be done to have proper scaling to work along with custom ticks and labels.

I tried changing the ticks count on default code on c3 js bar chart code, after that I gave values attribute and set values like this: values:[25,50,75,100].

But those are not being displayed as it should be, only 25% is displayed, but I doubt that actual scaling is working.

```
           var QosScoreChart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#qosScore',
                    data: {
                           x: 'x',
                    columns: [
                               surveyCountArr,
                                qosMonthArr,
                                qosTBArr,
                                qosBBArr 
                             ],

                     y2 axis 
                             axes:{
                              TopBox:'y',
                              BottomBox:'y',
                              Surveys:'y2'
                             },
                         types: {
                            TopBox: 'spline',
                            BottomBox: 'spline',
                            Surveys: 'bar',
                                },
                          labels: {
                                format: {
                                    Surveys: d3.format(""),
                                }}
                      },
                      bar: {width: 30},

                     axis: {
                              x: {
                                   type: 'category'
                                 },


                            y2:{
                                show:true,
                                padding: {
                                  top: 100, bottom: 10
                                        },
                                 max: 100,
                                },


                            y: {
                                max: 1,
                                 padding: {
                                       top: 100, bottom:0
                                          },

                                 tick:{
                                 format:d3.format("%"),
                                 values:[25,50,75,100],
                                      count: 4
                                      },


                               },
                           },
                     color: {
                     pattern: ['#92CFF6' ,'#2CA02C', '#F72107']
                    }
                   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a 0-100% percentage format, the values need to be less than 1

Try

```
 values:[0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00],
```

Of course the data points will need to be in the same range too